# How does keras(or any other ML framework) calculate the gradient of a lambda function layer for backpropagation?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

Keras enables adding a layer which calculates a user defined lambda function.
What I don't get is how Keras knows to calculate the gradient of this user defined function for the backpropagation.

Answer (score 7):

That one of the benefit of using Theano/Tensorflow and libraries build on top of them. They can give you automatic gradient calculation of the mathematical functions and operations.

Keras gets them by calling:

```
# keras/theano_backend.py
def gradients(loss, variables):
    return T.grad(loss, variables)

# keras/tensorflow_backend.py
def gradients(loss, variables):
    '''Returns the gradients of `variables` (list of tensor variables)
    with regard to `loss`.
    '''
    return tf.gradients(loss, variables, colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)
```

which are in turn called by the optimizers(keras/optimizers.py) `grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)` to get the gradients which are used to write the update rule for all the `params`. `params` here are the trainable weights of the layers. But layers created by the Lambda functional layers don't have any trainable weights. But they affect the loss function though the forward prob and hence indirectly affect the calculation of the gradients of trainable weights of other layers.

The only time you need to write new gradient calculation is when you are defining a new basic mathematical operation/function. Also, when you write a custom loss function the auto grad almost always takes care of the gradient calculation. But optionally you can optimize training (not always) if you implement analytical gradient of your custom functions. For example softwax function can be expressed in exp, sum and div and auto grad can take care of it, but its analytical/symbolic grad is usually implemented in Theano/Tensorflow.

For implementing new Ops you can see the below links for that:
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/extending_theano.html
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html